# XPath expression result in another Expression

Tags: xpath

I'd like to know if it's possible to have the result of an XPath expression "inside" another expression. For example:

I have this expression:

```
/equipment1/equipment2/equipment3[NAME="TEST"]/Value
```

And I need the result of that expression concatenated in this expression:

```
test/test2/test3[Id=EQUIPMENT:--HERE THE RESULT OF THE EXPRESSION!!!!--]
```

Is that possible to build? If so, how?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: give the html or xml part and tell how the output you are looking for..

Comment: What version of XPath?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually the expression I'm looking for in this case is(when the result of /equipment1/equipment2/equipment3[NAME="TEST"]/Value is "1"):   test/test2/test3[Id=EQUIPMENT:1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variables: evaluate the first expression, bind the result to a variable, and then use this variable in the second expression.

```
/test/test2/test3[@Id=concat("EQUIPMENT:", $param)]
```

Details of how to bind variable/parameter values depend on the XPath API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <p id='foo:1'>foo</p>
  <p id='foo:2'>bar</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

**XPATH 1.0:**

```
//div/p[@id = concat('foo:',//div[2]/p[1])]
```

**XPATH 2.0:**

```
//div/p[@id = string-join(('foo:',//div[2]/p[1]),"")]
```

**output**

```
<p id="foo:1">foo</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. There might be some slight changes needed, but assuming `NAME`, `Value` and `Id` are node attributes and `"EQUIPMENT:"` is a string, then

This is the first expression:

```
/equipment1/equipment2/equipment3[@NAME="TEST"]/@Value
```

This is the second one:

```
/test/test2/test3[@Id=concat("EQUIPMENT:", here-goes-the-first-expr)]
```

And both combined:

```
/test/test2/test3[@Id=concat("EQUIPMENT:", /equipment1/equipment2/equipment3[@NAME="TEST"]/@Value)]
```

I used the [`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat) function to concatenate both strings.

---

**EDIT**, because what I proposed as a solution seems to be a dirty hack. As Michael Kay kindly explained:

> In general this solution is WRONG, because the context for the
>   evaluation of the inner expression is incorrect. It happens to work
>   for this example, but is wrong in general. In addition, building
>   expressions by string concatenation is vulnerable to code injection
>   attacks. Use variables.

Therefore this solution, while working under OP's concrete conditions, *should not be used on real production*. If you really use this, please be very, very cautious.

Comment: Thank you very much Slanec. I just removed the "@" and it worked perfectly!

Comment: In general this solution is WRONG, because the context for the evaluation of the inner expression is incorrect. It happens to work for this example, but is wrong in general. In addition, building expressions by string concatenation is vulnerable to code injection attacks. Use variables.

Comment: @Dalek Edited the answer after Michael Kay's comment. Please use the solution cautiously.